# Two many values to unpack (expected two)

Tags: python, django, database, django-views, django-queryset

I'm making a python project for returning recipes with certain genres or ingredients. I'm getting a two many values to unpack error thrown when I am trying to create the genre in my database.

```
def createbgenre(request):
    BreakfastGenre.objects.create(genre=request.POST['genre'],user=User.objects.get(request.POST['user']))
    return redirect ('/breakfast')
```

this breakfastgenre object creation is throwing the error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre] so we can duplicate the behavior you're seeing. Please also include sample input and the **full text** of the error and traceback.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by this:

```
user=User.objects.get(request.POST['user'])
```

The field which this value will be filtered against needs to be specified. So assuming `request.POST['user']` contains the user id, this then needs to be used like:

```
user=User.objects.get(pk=request.POST['user'])
                    # ^^^ Filter against primary key
```